# Counting distinct values in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pivot tables, trying to write code to display the number of consumer accounts for each customer. I have the following so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'custID':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4],
              'accountID':[1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2],
              'tenure_mo':[2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7],
             'account_type':['BusiNESS','CONSUMER',
                            'consumer',
                            'BUSINESS',
                            'BuSIness',
                            'CONSUmer',
                            'consumer',
                            'CONSUMER',
                            'BUSINESS']},columns=['custID','accountID','tenure_mo','account_type'])
print(df1)
df2=pd.DataFrame({'custID':[1,2,3,4],
             'cust_age':[20,35,50,85]},columns=['custID','cust_age'])
```

This is my **desired output**:

```
custID num_cons_accounts
     1                 1
     2                 1
     3                 2
     4                 1
```

How can I modify/expand my code to produce this output?

Comment: Using groupby: `df.groupby["custID"].count()`

Answer (score 5):

According to your description the following code should work:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'custID':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4],
              'accountID':[1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2],
              'tenure_mo':[2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7],
             'account_type':['BusiNESS','CONSUMER',
                            'consumer',
                            'BUSINESS',
                            'BuSIness',
                            'CONSUmer',
                            'consumer',
                            'CONSUMER',
                            'BUSINESS']},columns=['custID','accountID','tenure_mo','account_type'])

df1 = df1[df1['account_type'].str.lower() == "consumer"]

print(df1.groupby("custID").count())
```

Select where lowercase version of account type is equal to `"consumer"` and then get counts for each `custID`.

The output:

```
        accountID  tenure_mo  account_type
custID                                    
1               1          1             1
2               1          1             1
3               2          2             2
4               1          1             1
```

A side note: if you want only the one column, drop the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

use set to find the distinct count of accounts by account_type2 using an apply and lambda function

```
 df1=pd.DataFrame({'custID':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4],
          'accountID':[1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2],
          'tenure_mo':[2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7],
         'account_type':['BusiNESS','CONSUMER','consumer','BUSINESS','BuSIness','CONSUmer',
                        'consumer', 'CONSUMER','BUSINESS']},columns=['custID','accountID','tenure_mo','account_type'])

 df1['account_type2']=df1['account_type'].apply(lambda row: row.lower())
 
 grouped=df1.groupby('custID').apply(lambda row: len(set(row.account_type2)))
 print(grouped)
```

output:

```
 custID distinct count
 1    2
 2    2
 3    1
 4    2
```